# how to display data in format using javascript extract from mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, html

This is what i get to render data in view when I extract from the database as well as when "Exception" comes i want to show in new line.  But I want to display them in proper manner in single sring

```
The requirements of this chapter apply to the following: (1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1) (2) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4) Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.(3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4) (4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.
```

I want to display this in the following order in dynamically

The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:

```
(1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1)

 (2) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4) 

Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.

(3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4) 

(4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.
```

While I am doing this in javascript. Where I get this content in section_data.title. How can I manage to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that your line breaks aren't in html. Try using `str_replace('\n', '<br>', $queryResultString);` in your PHP before writing encoding it as JSON (replacing $queryResultString with whatever strings you're sending through JSON).

Let me know if this works, or we can try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript method "String[] split(String regex)" to split the string according to regular expression and store in array.Then you can add breakline tags to format it.

Comment: actually I am new to javascript so I could not understand it properly if you can write code to me..that would be very helpful.. thank you

Comment: You have code for yourself ,I can only provide hints. Search google for split method and try it yourself.
Good luck.